# Function execution order in python

Tags: python, function, speech-recognition, execution

for some reason my function "transcription" executes the API before playing a sound that is supposed to notify that one is asked to speak into the microphone.

I don't understand why all of a sudden the general linear execution order is broken.

Any suggestions?

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
### instantiate pycharm
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


acknowledge_wav = ["asyouwish.wav", "openingdesired.wav", "rightaway.wav"]

keywords = {"firefox": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe",
            "discord": "C:/Users/LucasGames/AppData/Local/Discord/Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe",
            "pycharm": "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1/bin/pycharm64.exe",
            "chrome": "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
            "wars": "C:/Spiele/steamapps/common/Jedi Outcast/GameData/JK2MV/jk2mvmp.exe"
            }

with sr.Microphone(sample_rate=20000) as mic:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.5)
    audio = r.listen(mic)

### play some sound
def play_sound(file):
    wf = wave.open(file)
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)
    wav_data = wf.readframes(1024)

    while len(wav_data) > 0:
        stream.write(wav_data)
        wav_data = wf.readframes(1024)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

### activation and transcription of recognizer
def transcription(audio_data):
    ## speak now indicator
    play_sound("notificationtest.wav")
 
    ## call google API
    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="en-USA").lower()
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("I am experiencing brain fog - please try again.")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("I could not understand you. Please repeat your command.")

    # splits the command sentence in single words to iterate over
    splt_command = command.split()

    ## check if keyword is in the spoken command
    for word in splt_command:
        if word in keywords:
            print(f"Command: {command}")
            print(f"Keyword: {word}")
            assistant_response = random.choice(acknowledge_wav)
            play_sound(assistant_response)
            subprocess.call(keywords[word])

    # no keyword in command
    print("No keyword detected.")
    print(f"Said: {command}")

transcription(audio)
```

Comment: The sound data is probably buffered, and writing to the sound device doesn't wait for it to be played.

Comment: Where did the `audio` parameter that you're passing to `transcription()` come from?  You've already received that audio somehow before the function even starts executing, therefore any "speak now" prompt given in the function is too late.

Comment: I have edited the above code in order to answer where audio is coming from.
So if I understand correctly I need to include the microphone method in my transcription function and place the "speak now" before it.